# Vue check when async component has loaded

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component

I am wondering how to check when an async component has loaded.

Normally I would load my component like so:

```
Vue.component(
     'booking-overlay', 
     () => import('@/components/BookingOverlayAsync.vue')
);
```

Using something like this does not work:

```
Vue.component(
   'booking-overlay',
    () => import('@/components/BookingOverlayAsync.vue').then(() => {
        console.log('component has loaded');
    })
);
```

It leads to the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '__esModule' of undefined at ensureCtor..

The component no longer loads but the promise does resolve though. By adding the `then` it no longer resolves the promise itself it seems.

How can I globally register this async component and also check when this components chunk of JavaScript has been loaded?

Obviously I could simply do this together with setting the global component:

```
import('@/components/BookingOverlayAsync.vue').then(() => {
    console.log('Chunk loaded');
});
```

This just seems like a very ugly solution though.

Comment: Can you show the code of targeted vue component you are going to load asynchronously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your second promise object returned by .then function doesn't continue to hand down the async loaded component to vue lib itself.

the Vue.component function expects that the **second** parameter should be a function that returns a promise where the resolved data must be the async-loaded component itself.

please try following:

```js
Vue.component(
        'booking-overlay',
        () => import('@/components/BookingOverlayAsync.vue').then(component => {
            console.log('component has loaded');
            return component;
        })
    );
```

Comment: That was a lot more obvious than I thought it would be. It works now. Thanks for your help.